# Scroll to bottom of webview programmatically with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I have the following webview:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView_MyContent: UIWebView!
```

and load custom html content like so:

```
self.webView_MyContent.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

I would like to scroll to the very bottom of the page programmatically when my content loads.  How would this be accomplished in swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`scrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617955-scrollview) property of `UIWebView` for that.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height - webView.frame.size.height)
    webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)//Set false if you doesn't want animation
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set `delegate` of your `webView`.

Comment: @user2423476 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me with Swift 4 / WKWebView.

Instead I found the method [`webView.scrollToEndOfDocument()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding/3005279-scrolltoendofdocument)

To scroll down after loading is finished you can put it into this function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)
}
```

Don't forget to import WebKit and to make your class the delegate of your WebView:

```
// ...
import WebKit
// ...

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    // ...
```

---

### Advanced: scroll down after finishing AJAX requests

Now in my case I wanted to scroll down a page that used infinite scroll (when nearly reaching the end of the page it starts loading additional content).

This can be done by injecting JavaScript and overwriting the XMLHttpRequest method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...

    String javascript = String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js"))
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "injectionHandler")
    webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript.init(source: javascript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false))

    // ...

}
```

And in the file `script.js` in your Xcode project you'll put this:

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    this.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var message = {"status": this.status, "requestUrl": url, "response": this.responseText, "responseURL": this.responseURL};
        webkit.messageHandlers.injectionHandler.postMessage(message);
    });
    open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

To handle this event (and if you want also catch the AJAX response) you have to add this method:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "injectionHandler", let dict = message.body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let status = dict["status"] as? Int, let response = dict["response"] as? String {
        if status == 200 {
            webView.scrollToEndOfDocument()
        }
    }
}
```

and make your class extend WKScriptMessageHandler:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    // ...
```

Comment: The question is about iOS. This `webView.scrollToEndOfDocument()` belongs to `AppKit` framework, from `macOS 10.14+`.